# Java Framework for developing puzzle games (Jigsaw, for instance)

Tags: java, user-interface, puzzle

I'm developing some puzzle games, and I thought I'd choose Java because I'd get less compatibility issues to deal with. But before I 'jump', I just want to make sure it is the reasonable choice.

So does anyone know of a good framework for building GUI puzzle games in Java?
I've done some googling and saw some game-engine frameworks out there, but I don't think the kind of games of doing need a game engine (though I could be wrong, because I am not a game-programmer). From my limited understanding, for building puzzles, I'd just need some nice GUI (preferably not the old-fashion Swing components!)

And to elaborate, I do not need fancy 3D GUI. Just something like this is sufficient.
On the top of my head, I don't remember how Java's pure Swing API could do something like that. (Note the pieces are pluggable to one another.)

[image: Sample]

Comment: If you really want the *least* compatibility issues, develop this using HTML and Javscript. It will then run on pretty much anything with a browser, including all phones and tablets.

Comment: Swing and `Graphics2D` should be more than enough for what you want to achieve.  Check out [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for the basics and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) for more advance APIs

Comment: Why are you  'CLOSING' my question???? Where do you suggest the question be asked if this is not the appropriate forum?????

Comment: @user1508893 It might be better suited for [programmers.stackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much any GUI framework will have the ability to create a puzzle layout like you describe. Although you probably won't find ready-made puzzle piece components in a GUI toolkit, you can almost always use some kind of canvas and image drawing primitives to draw exactly what you want. I have in the past used Swing to create a GUI that is all custom and doesn't look like a Swing app (see http://free15c.com, the code itself is on GitHub).

It's unlikely that you would need (or want) a full game engine framework. There is more than enough capability in the standard GUI libraries to do this.

Finally, as I mentioned above in a comment, for maximum compatibility with devices of all shapes and sizes, you might consider using an HTML/Javascript implementation. This kind of click-and-drag moving images about would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't think (and maybe still don't) HTML/Javascript would be suitable, because it is not just a simple jigsaw (it sure does look like one!). The application has certain components that need to be implemented in JavaCC ans Assembly.

Comment: Ah, well that requirement certainly wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: I've got to ask, how didyou make the buttons on the calculator look like they are actually being pushed down when one clicks on them? I don't imagine you just set the background of each [J]button to be the image of the 'real' button, then arrange them on some kind of panel (JPanel?) so that they match the positions of the real buttons? It must have been tedious work.

Comment: Each key is a `JButton` that has an `ImageIcon` that takes its image from the underlying photographic image. There is an icon set with `setPressedIcon()` that takes its image from one pixel offset from the base image. Each `JButton` is positioned explicitly with `setBounds()`. See [`CalcFrame.java` for the relevant bits of code](https://github.com/ghewgill/hp15c/blob/master/swing/CalcFrame.java#L420).